# A lost preprint by Kontsevich and Soibelman

Tags: reference-request, online-resources, deformation-theory

In Markl's article [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0601129.pdf#page47) he references under the number [57] the following article

> M. Kontsevich and Y. Soibelman. Deformation theory of bialgebras, Hopf algebras and tensor categories. Preprint, March 2002.

Unfortunately, I couln't find the preprint neither online nor in my university library. Does anybody have a copy?

Comment: can you not find something relevant here ? https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/beem/papers/kontsevich_soibelman_deformation_theory_1.pdf

Comment: Checking https://www.ihes.fr/~maxim/publicationsfrancais.html && https://www.math.ksu.edu/~soibel/2008-vita.pdf , I see the Common Publications , which are mostly in agreement. Yet the Paper you want is not listed. I would guess that  either that Paper got retracted or It got converted to something else or Markl made a mistake in typing the Paper Name or Markl made a mistake in the Author Name !